# How to change the display height of this PDF-to-HTML converted page?

Tags: html

I have a document which I recently converted from PDF to HTML. All I want to do is to change the display height of a page like this:

Suppose this is the original page:

Original Page which I want to edit
[image: Original Page which I want to edit]

The resultant page I want after editing:

Resultant page after editing
[image: Resultant page after editing]
The HTML of Original source page is:

view-source:http://19216811.live/1net1-r90-manual/2

Can anybody please help?

Comment: At least say what language or technology you are using.

Comment: I am using JPDF2HTML Converter module from IDRSoultions.com. But I think it is irrelevant for this question. I have provided the source code for the given page, above, in question. Can you please tell what changes I can made to HTML/CSS code to hide the above part of the page, as shown in image above...